# web crawler in rails,how to crawl all pages of the site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler, resque, anemone

I need to get  all urls from all pages of the given domain,
I think it make sense to use background jobs, placing them on multiple queues
 
trying to use [cobweb](https://github.com/stewartmckee/cobweb) but it seems very confusing gem, 
and [anomone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/), anemone is working for a long time if there are a lot of pages

```
require 'anemone'

Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_every_page do |page|
      puts page.links
  end
end
```

What do u think would fit me best?

Comment: Do you need to generate Sitemap for your Site ?

Comment: @AjayKumar No, I just need to get all links from the site

Comment: wget httrack and there many other spider you can use

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Nutch` Crawler, [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is a highly extensible and scalable open source web crawler software project.

Comment: I think cobweb fit me best